# Connecting to MacBook Air 2017 with usb-c connection

Tags: macbook-pro, usb

I have my work computer that I connect to my dual monitor setup, and my MacBook Air 2017 that I can't since it doesn't have a usb-c port.

Is there any way I can use the same hub with ubc-c connection for my MacBook?

Comment: Just to clarify, you would like to connect your USB-C hub to your 2017 MacBook Air? And if so, it the hub USB-C, or Thunderbolt 3?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have a USB hub/dock with a USB-C connection....

The answer is no because the USB ports on your MBA is USB 3.0 while the USB-C connection is at minimum, 3.1.  USB is *backward compatible* with downstream devices and in your case, the downstream device (the hub) is a higher spec.

Comment: I have a thunderbolt 2 port that I use to connect to a single monitor, is there any way I can use that?

Comment: See this answer instead (posted wrong one initially):  https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/265917/using-a-usb-c-dock-with-older-macbook-pros/267009#267009