# Macbook Pro docking station - backward compatibility?

Tags: dock, thunderbolt, thunderbolt-display

I have a 15" 2015 Macbook Pro issued to me by my workplace.  I also have a 13" 2020 Macbook Pro for personal use.

The 2015 has Thunderbolt 2, and the new one has Thunderbolt 3.  I have a StarTech Thunderbolt 3 (USB-C) docking station, which works fine with the 13" 2020.  I would like to be able to connect my 2015 MBP to the same docking station.

It appears that I could use [this adapter](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MMEL2/thunderbolt-3-usb-c-to-thunderbolt-2-adapter?fnode=4), in tandem with a Thunderbolt 2 cable, to "reverse" connect the 2015 MBP to the docking station. I don't need to use the USB ports on the docking station, just two 1080p/60Hz displays and perhaps Ethernet (WiFi is OK).

I have read hypotheses that this will work, but am wondering if anyone has successfully done this themselves. Looking for testimonials!

Comment: On the page you linked to, at the bottom. Click on the "+" to the right of questions and answers. Someone posted an answer to a similar question. Wondering if that answers your question

Comment: I've written an answer to this very question:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/398385/119271  That said, I can't tell you how many times I've heard "I don't need this that or the other" and "all I need is X" and then shortly after the user wants to do something that the device simply can't do and is then is upset because a) wasted money and b) wasted time.  Take a moment and really evaluate if this is the path you want to go down.